# Pointers versus arrays for semi-known inputs in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Suppose I have a struct as follows (this is in C):

```
typedef struct Cage {
  int cage_size;
  int sum;
  int** elements;
} Cage;
```

In my input file, my inputs are read in as follows:

```
size a
sum b
x y value
x y value
...

size a
...
```

Where a, b, x, y, and value are all integers. `a` corresponds to `cage_size`, `b` to `sum`, and `elements` is an array ordered as `{x, y, value, x, y, value ...}`. I have a double pointer to contain all of the `cage` structs, as I do not know the number of structs (or the number of `x y value` tuples) at compile-time.

My question is: I have an unknown number of `x y value` tuples, but I know that I will always have three inputs per tuple. How would one parse the tuples? Would storing them like I currently do (in a double pointer) make sense? E.g:

```
int* elements[3]; //would this be a good choice? Is this even legal?

int** elements;   //current set-up, but having pointers like this isn't great and 
                  //I suspect I can do better

int* elements;    //this might be easiest to use once I have it, 
                  //but how would I allocate the memory when parsing the inputs? 
                  //Maybe I could parse all the lines and store them into a buffer first?
```

I'm looking for a good solution, not a quick fix. I'm trying to get my head around C and effective IO/memory allocation.

Comment: Use a *pointer to array of int [3]*, e.g. `int (*elements)[3];` Then allocate some reasonable initial number and then `realloc` as required. **note the difference** `int *elements[3]` is *an array of pointers to int* (3 of them) while `int (*elements)[3]` is a *pointer to array of 3 ints*.

Comment: 1) Only use `fgets()` to read the lines.  2) Read the 2 initial lines 3) save file position with `ftell()`  4) read and count tuples until EOF or next "size a" 5) re-read tuples this time saving.  6) continue with next "size a".

Comment: use `int *` point to single memory block, and just read/write items 3 at a time

Answer (score 2):

All of them works. The best solution cannot be determined from a small example. It all depends on how you're going to use the data later on.

Regarding how to parse the tuples, one way is to first `malloc` a chunk of memory and then use `realloc` if necessary. Another option is to read the file until you find the first non 3-tuple and then backtrack.

Pseudo for first option:

```
size = 1
tuples = malloc(size)
while(nextLine is a tuple)
  size++ 
  tuples = realloc(size)
  tuples[i]=nextLine
```

Pseudo for second option:

```
size=0
while(nextLine is a tuple)
  size++
backtrack
tuples=malloc(size)
```

Comment: `realloc` doesn't overwrite memory, does it? That was what I was wondering. And given that the end of the list of tuples is a line break (before the next cage potentially), would I do something like `strstr({get buffer}, "\n") == null` to check for that empty line?

Comment: Nope, `realloc` does not overwrite memory. Neither does `malloc`. However, `calloc` zeros the memory you allocate. Read the manuals. And regarding the empty line, I'm sure you'll figure it out. Otherwise, post a new question. :)

Comment: Never assign the result of `realloc` to the variable itself. If `realloc` fails it returns `NULL` and you have just lost your reference to your existing data and created a memory leak. Instead, `void *tmp = realloc (tuples, size); if (!tmp) {handle error}; tuples = tmp;`.

Answer (score 0):

One Idea that might work is to make another struct for your `x y value` tuples, say `XYTuple,` and then have `XYTuble* tuples=(XYTuple*) malloc(sizeof(XYTuple)*<count>);`

Comment: The point is that I don't know the number of tuples though, klutt points out that I'd need to reallocate the memory.

Comment: you don't know the number of `int*`'s or `int[3]`'s either, I was just suggesting that using another struct to manage that aspect and make it easier to focus on the re allocation that you need to do